# CUPS Printer Server

Tags: printing

I am in the process of building a print server for my organisation. I want to make it possible for pc's on one subnet to be able to print on another subnet. I was wondering if anyone maybe have tips for me? I am using an Ubuntu 14.04 server which are connected to both subnets. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well for example we have a few subnets like, 192.168.1.* and 192.168.5.* on our subnet each subnet  with different purposes but people on the one subnet needs to be able to print to network printers on the other subnet

Answer (score 0):

### Using CUPS

provided that people from both subnet can connect to your server, you can use easy-to-setup `CUPS`

1. Open the CUPS admin web frontend (https://servername:631/admin)
2. Click "Add Printer" on the "Administration" tab
3. Choose the way that your printer is connected and enter the appropriate URL. Examples:

LPD protocol:

```
lpd://hostname/queue
```

Internet Printing Protocol

```
ipp://hostname/ipp/port
```

Forwarding the jobs to a Windows print server (Note: Vista and higher don't allow anonymous connects by default. You have to provide a username and password for the connection)

```
smb://username:password@domain/servername/printername
```

1. Enter a name for the printer
2. Choose "Raw" for the printer vendor and model
3. Save the the settings

[Reference](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_a_Samba_print_server#CUPS)

---

### Using SAMBA

*I am recommending SAMBA because sometimes it is easy to deal with*

If your client's Windows version is below Windows 2000 or if you experienced troubles with IPP you can also use Samba for sharing. Note of course that with Samba this involves another complex piece of software. This makes this way more difficult to configure and thus sometimes also more error-prone, mostly due to authentication problems.

To configure Samba on the Linux server, edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file to allow access to printers. File `smb.con`f can look something like this:

`/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
[global]
workgroup=Heroes
server string=Arch Linux Print Server
security=user

[printers]
    comment=All Printers
    path=/var/spool/samba
    browseable=yes
    # to allow user 'guest account' to print.
    guest ok=no
    writable=no
    printable=yes
    create mode=0700
    write list=@adm root yourusername
```

[Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Printer_sharing)

Comment: Thank you, if my clients are macs, most of our clients Ubuntu, Mac and a few windows

Comment: @user238156 I think samba is better because it works with all OS: windows, linux and Mac. what problem you are facing? did you try first part?

Comment: Well I will only be able to try it out on Monday. I am based in Russia. So time differences makes things slightly difficult. One thing I would also like to do is that not all the printers will be easily visible. Maybe password protected or that you need to know the path of the printer. So I need samba and cups, you think? I will try it out on Monday. Thank you

Comment: @user238156 both the options are available. printers with password and  printers without password.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it on Monday and will let you know. Thank you so much